# how to change orientation of UIViewController to Landscape programmatically?

Tags: ios, orientation, landscape

I want to change the orientation of my UIViewController shown using `presentModalViewController` ... I saw a couple of solutions online (including SO). However, none of them solved my problem.

I am showing some video here and want to change the screen orientation to landscape .. any help ?

Thanks.

using this code I solved my problem partially: (my view controller just does landscape for LandscapeLEFT and NOT for LandscapeRIGHT==>for LandscapeRight, it still does a LandscapeLEFT orientation change in the view controller) ... any help ??????????

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to force rotation, or allow rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Returning [YES] will ensure all interface oprientations are supported in your app.

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return YES;
  }

Comment: am using this currently: `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}` but doesn't help :(